# How can I export a certificate from MMC as a PFX file?

Tags: certificate, export, mmc

I'm in the process of trying to change the KeySpec property of a code signing certificate from Comodo by following [this guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrekl/2008/01/08/strong-name-signing-in-visual-studio-2005-requires-keyspec2-at_signature/). The guide mentions importing your certificate file into MMC and then exporting it again later. However, I don't seem to have the option to export as a PFX file. I already have a PFX file; I can import it successfully, but when I go to export the option is greyed out / disabled.

[image: pfx disabled]

What do I need to do to enable this export option?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The Certificates snap-in really doesn't like to export PFX certificates, but PowerShell is happy to. You can use the [`Export-PfxCertificate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/export-pfxcertificate) cmdlet.

1. Go to the certificates pseudo-drive by typing `cd cert:\` at the PowerShell prompt.
2. Type `cd CurrentUser` or `cd LocalMachine` as appropriate for where the certificate is. You may need to launch PowerShell as admin to export a machine certificate.
3. `cd` into the appropriate store (a `dir` may help). The Personal store in MMC is called `My` here.
4. Use `dir` to identify which ID corresponds to the certificate you want.
5. Type this command to export it as a PFX with a password:

   ```
   Export-PfxCertificate -Cert .\LONGSTRINGOFHEX -FilePath 'C:\path\to\outfile.pfx' -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'password' -AsPlainText -Force)
   ```

   `LONGSTRINGOFHEX` should be replaced with your certificate's ID. Fortunately, you can use tab completion on that.

Once that command executes, you have a PFX certificate protected with the password you supplied. PowerShell refuses to export the certificate's private key without a password, and the password can't be blank. Nevertheless, your PFX is out.

Comment: Please forgive such an ignorant question, but how do I install the cmdlet? Currently when I type `cert:` in PS I get "The term 'cert:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program." Windows 10 of course.

Comment: @SoaperGEM My apologies, it should be ```cd cert:\``` instead.

Comment: @SoaperGEM This cmdlet is available in Windows 8, 8.1, 10, Server 2012 and Server 2012 R2. Judging by your screenshot, you are set.

Also, when importing your certificate, look for a checkbox that allows you to mark the private key as exportable. That should give you the ability to export it via MMC.

Comment: I am getting error - Cannot export non-exportable private key. Can anyone help identify the issue.

Comment: @RajaDorji If a private key was marked as non-exportable, the system generally refuses to export. Tools like Mimikatz ([mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3914882/2825369)) can get around this through unofficial methods.

Comment: @BenN thank you for your reply. I raised csr request on windows server with keytool and am unaware of any step of marking key as exportable. Maybe we are not installing the certificates correctly. I added a question https://serverfault.com/questions/943496/how-to-install-cer-and-p7b-certificates-to-use-in-iis 
Please take a look, appreciate your time.

Comment: Where do you obtain the certificate's ID?

Comment: @MC9000 It's the certificate's thumbprint, which is one of the entries in the list visible by opening `certmgr.msc`, double-clicking the certificate, and going to the Details tab.

Comment: Thanks! Also trying to fix Sectigo madness (since Comodo changed their name, everything went to hell with intermediate certificates) - that'll be another post

Comment: This is case-sensitive as I've discovered (the Id/thumbprint must be in upper case).  Got the dreaded "Cannot export non-exportable private key." message.
Dang!

Comment: This did not work for me unfortunately - and the issue I had was that I was generating the CSR from myasp.net and they don't give any option in the CSR generation about the exporting of the key. But when trying to install the certificate, it would not accept the .cer or .crt file generated by the SSL provider. Ultimately, I generated a CSR from my local IIS, installed the SSL back on the same and then exported and installed that .pfx on myASP.net and that worked. Hope this helps someone. IF YOUR SSL IS MARKED NOT TO ALLOW EXPORT, THIS COMMAND WILL NOT WORK.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had created the CSR file on one machine and then tried to create the pfx file on another (Windows 10 had done an update overnight and locked me out of the first machine). Both the CSR and the pfx file need to be created on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you import a cert into the WebHosting store, you can't export the private key.  Move it to Personal store, and you will be able to export as PFX. 
I was able to do this in Windows 2012R2 without having to go to the command line and use Export-PfxCertificate (which is a pain as I couldn't figure out the certificate's ID to save my life).

Comment: Okay, I'm wrong. Just got lucky.  I had to try this task again (reissued a cert), and this method does not work anymore :(

Comment: You can find the Certificate's ID by either going to **IIS > Machine > Server Certificates** or by `cd cert:\LocalMachine\My` then 'dir'

Answer (score -3):

Export the .P7B file once.
And then go back and try exporting the certificate again. The .PFX export get enabled the next time.

Comment: That certainly does not work!

Comment: Did not work for me either.